# How do I force my launch storyboard to appear in portrait on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uistoryboard, launchimage

My app supports only iPhone, and the three default orientations (portrait, landscape left, landscape right).

I have a launch storyboard. If my iPhone 7 Plus is in landscape mode on the home screen when I launch my app, the storyboard appears in landscape mode. How do I tell iOS to always display the storyboard in portrait mode, as if the device were in portrait mode before the app was launched?

Please don't ask why I want this, or tell me it's a bad idea — there's context that would be a distraction to go into in this question.

Comment: Yes, It is possible..

Comment: How do I do it?